# how to move an android project to another compute without error

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android project, but once my friend transfer his project file to me, it always cost me some issue.

It always has "cannot resolve the symbol 'AppCompatActivity'"

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

I copied the project file from user/admin/android studio/my project name folder into another computer with same address.

Comment: Git your code and then simply clone it;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:${latestversion}
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${latestversion}
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${latestversion}
    compile 'com.android.support:design:${latestversion}
}
```

Clean - Sync - Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to tell you how to fix your current error as others have already answered that.

So, to answer your question, the best way to transfer an android project (or any other code) to another computer without any error is to use a GIT repository. Push your files from the source computer and pull them at target computer, as simple as that.